# É possível capturar código PHP de uma página utilizando CURL?

Tags: php

Como faço para executar o código PHP de uma determinada página dentro da minha aplicação, sendo que eu não sou detentor dessa aplicação.

Comment: Como assim? O que você quer fazer?

Comment: Quero uma linha de código php que execute um arquivo php de outro servidor.

Comment: Você só precisa incluir o arquivo dentro do arquivo atual. `include`, `include_once`, `require` ou `require_once`.

Comment: Boa Noite, não é bem que eu quero, o que eu quero é utilizar o curl para ler outro arquivo php

Comment: Então explique melhor, a pergunta não está muito clara. Se não tem código, exemplifique com mais detalhes o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Por exemplo. Eu tenho o arquivo x no servidor a e tenho o arquivo y no servidor b. Eu quero que o arquive x tenha uma linha que execute o arquivo y no servidor b. Tudo com php

Comment: Executar um código de outra página é bem diferente de "ler outra página". seja específico ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível executar um código PHP de terceiro pelo fato de que o código PHP é enviado para o servidor, processado e depois retorna uma saída em HTML, o que é possível fazer é capturar somente esta saída, e utilizar somente os parâmetros de entrada de dados, como GET ou POST.

O CURL, apenas captura a página como foi processada pelo servidor (isso se o servidor de terceiro permitir e se você tiver CURL instalada no seu apache), se você quer utilizar somente isso, este é o código para capturar:

```
function capturarUrl($url_metodo)
{

    try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_metodo);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $saida = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            $saida = file_get_contents($url_metodo);
    }
    return $saida;
}

echo capturarUrl('http://www.google.com.br');
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui, mas eu não recomendo isso, porque eu só uso cURL para pegar o HTML de uma página e tratar. Por exemplo, quando eu quero os dados sobre inflação do site do Banco Central, eu uso cURL.

```
#cria uma variável com a inicialização da função
$curl = curl_init();

#passa as opções para a função cURL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "caminho/pro/seu/arquivo.php"); //URL do arquivo .PHP. A URL pode ser passada por variavel também $url = "caminho/pro/seu/arquivo.php"
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); //nao incluir os cabeçalhos na saida/resultado
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //retorna o curl_exec() como uma string, em vez de imprimir diretamente

#executa a sessão cURL
$resultado = curl_exec($curl);
#fecha a sessão cURL
curl_close($curl);

#imprime o resultado
echo $resultado;
```

A `curl_init()` pode receber a URL diretamente também: `curl_init("caminho/do/arquivo.php")`. Nesse caso, você pode remover `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url`.

Comment: -1 Ele irá obter o HTML da página, não o PHP que é a razão da pergunta. Sua resposta leva a crer que seria possível obter o PHP usando isto, embora somente use para HTML.

Comment: Bro, c'mon! não dá pra pegar o PHP da página, tenha bom senso, for goodness sake. O PHP roda no SERVIDOR, pra ter acesso a ele você tem que ter acesso ao servidor, o que só acontecerá se você for administrador ou tiver acesso de alguma forma a ele, inclusive ilegalmente.